# Difference between nginx ingress controller kind:service vs kind: Ingress vs kind: configMap in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to understand the difference between Nginx ingress controller

```
kind:service
```

vs

```
kind: Ingress
```

vs

```
kind: configMap
```

in Kubernetes but a little unclear.
Is kind: Service same as Kind: Ingress in Service and Ingress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**kind** represents the type of Kubernetes objects to be created while using the **yaml** file.

> [Kubernetes objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/) are persistent entities in the Kubernetes
> system. Kubernetes uses these entities to represent the state of your
> cluster. Specifically, they can describe:
>
> - What containerized applications are running (and on which nodes)
> - The resources available to those applications
> - The policies around how those applications behave, such as restart    policies, upgrades, and fault-tolerance
>
> [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) Object: A ConfigMap is an API object used to store
> non-confidential data in key-value pairs. Pods can consume ConfigMaps
> as environment variables, command-line arguments, or as configuration
> files in a volume.
>
> [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) Object: An API object that manages external access to the
> services in a cluster, typically HTTP. Ingress may provide load
> balancing, SSL termination and name-based virtual hosting.
>
> [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) Object: In Kubernetes, a Service is an abstraction which
> defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them
> (sometimes this pattern is called a micro-service).